# DocuSign Anchor Tab Not Modifiable

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign SOAP API in C# .NET application. I need to add an anchortab for the Company name. The tab is added but is modifiable by the signer. How do I disable so that the signer can not modify the value? The code is as below.

```
tab18 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
tab18.RecipientID = rcpt1.ID;
tab18.PageNumber = "17";
tab18.DocumentID = docId;
tab18.Type = DocuSignAPI.TabTypeCode.Company;
tab18.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
tab18.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = "Company Name:";
tab18.AnchorTabItem.Unit = DocuSignAPI.UnitTypeCode.Pixels;
tab18.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = 0;
tab18.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 50;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the behavior you've described by setting the tab's `Locked` property to `true`. For info about tab properties, see the [EnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/#/definitions/text) page in the DocuSign API docs.

Comment: That worked. I had to though first create a custom tab then set it to anchor tab. I could not find lock attribute to anchor tab, but found one for custom tab.